# Trying to delete a record from database using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, delete-record

[image]

Facing and Error Property [customer_id] does not exist on this collection instance.
[image]

But the column exsits in database table and $customer in and object instance of table
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `@foreach ($customer as $value)` so it should be `{{ $value->customer_id }}` in your `url()`.

```xml
<a href="{{ url('customer/delete/'.$value->customer_id) }}">
```